# Pairs whose names first characters are the same in a same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for SQL Query to show the names with the same first character in the same column.

```
Table: User
Column: Names
```

Comment: Select name 
From  [User]
Where SUBSTRING(name,1,1) = SUBSTRING(name,1,1)

Comment: [edit] any additional information into the question.

Comment: Only this functionality is required

Comment: If you have a table with a couple of hundred names, almost everyone will share the first character with someone else.

Comment: *"`Where SUBSTRING(name,1,1) = SUBSTRING(name,1,1)`"*? Apart from when a string has the value `NULL` that expression will always be true; there's no point in it or you might as well replace it with `WHERE [name] IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: What's the primary key of the table, or is it OK, when a name "finds" itself? Do you want pairs of names? If you want pairs, should they be ordered or not (i.e. would there be a row for the inverse order for every row (where the names aren't equal))? Does the result have to be distinct? [Edit] the question and elaborate on the conditions. Also add the [example] as @DaleK has already requested. Address the detailed requirements in it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the logic below -

```
Select T1.Names,
       T1.first_char
From
(Select 
      Names,
      substring(Names,1,1) as first_char
    From USER ) T1
 JOIN
  (Select 
      substring(Names,1,1) as first_char
      From USER
      Group by 
       substring(Names,1,1)
       having count(distinct Names) > 1) T2
  ON T1.first_char = T2.first_char;
```

EDIT : if you want to show the names together and if you are using SQL Server version 2017 or above, you can do -

```
Select 
       T1.first_char,
       String_Agg(T1.Names,',') within group (order by T1.Names) as Name_list
From
(Select 
      Names,
      substring(Names,1,1) as first_char
    From USER ) T1
 JOIN
  (Select 
      substring(Names,1,1) as first_char
      From USER
      Group by 
       substring(Names,1,1)
       having count(distinct Names) > 1) T2
  ON T1.first_char = T2.first_char
Group by T1.first_char;
```

Comment: You're not helping the OP learn to use this site by making up sample data and expected results for them. And you have no way of knowing whether what you are proposing is what the OP wants anyway.

Comment: Dale K -  Agreed with you. Questions should contain input and output sample data. That’s why I mentioned in the comment section that we should comply with SO guidelines. However, I don’t agree with you - “you have no way of knowing what you are proposing is what OP wants”. Not every problem needs to be spoonfeed to be understood, sometimes the problem statement is clear enough at least in my mind. You may have a different perception and perspective so no point to argue on that. And I think nobody is smart enough to be right 100% of the time. No one is 100% right or wrong always.

Comment: I'm not referring to your answer, I'm referring to your proposed edit to the question, which I have rejected, you should not be substantially editing a question. So when I say you have no way of knowing, your proposed sample data and expected results in the question edit may or may not be what the OP wants - and by adding it you are not only doing OPs work for them, but you could be plain wrong. Thats why OP needs to learn to update their question.

Comment: Again, I am completely aligned with you that anyone who asks a question should have at least these basic information on the question - input and output sample datasets. From that perspective, I am completely ok with you rejecting my edit to the question. If your thought process is - OP should learn how to put up question properly in this forum, I am 200% aligned with you.

Answer (score 0):

CROSS JOIN the User table and exclude the matching primary keys

```
SELECT u1.UserID, u1.Names, u2.UserId, u2.Names 
FROM User u1
CROSS JOIN User u2
WHERE LEFT(u1.Names, 1) LIKE LEFT(u2.Names, 1)
AND u1.UserID <> u2.UserID
```